# Grails 3.1.4 cannot run-app

Tags: grails, grails-3.1, run-app

I have just moved to the new Grails 3.1, and my first app in Grails worked fine. But when I created a another new Grails 3.1 app I ran into a new problem; the problem occurs when try to run using `run-app` interactively in the new application root:

```
| Running application...
Error: Could not find or load main class try3grails.Application

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with  non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

The class `try3grails.Application` referers to the first app's main method class I created; so the error seems to be that Grails cannot 'forget' the old app classpath. Does any one have a solution to this or is there something I missed?

Running `grails --version` gives:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.4
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_77
```

Grails is installed using SDKMan on a ubuntu linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are running `run-app` from the right directory.
Also try to do some cleaning:
`grails clean` could help.
If nothing helps - you can clear grails/gradle cache, or create a new app.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried `grails clean` and `run-app` outside the grails-app folder (where the gralde wrapper is located) but no dice. I have found a solution but that required updating the gradle wrapper from 2.9 to 2.12.

Comment: My problem started when I moved the Application.groovy to a new package.  grails clean didn't help.  I ended up removing the whole ~/.groovy directory and that fixed the issue (a cache issue I guess).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found "workaround" by updating the gradle wrapper version from 2.9 to 2.12(or 2.10 works too).

This is done by updating the version number in `gradle.properties`
and in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, and then executing:

```
./gradlew wrapper
```